# Filter Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, filter, tampermonkey

I need a function to filter a message in Javascript

the variable **msgText** is where the message you want to filt

she comes like this: **`<!-- react-text: 1052 -->Message Here<!-- /react-text -->`**

Here is where I call the function:

```
msgText = $(msgTextSelect).html();
msgText = analyseElem(msgText);
debug(msgText);
```

So, I want after the filter, it returns like this: **Message Here**

The filter that I've assembled is not working, so I wonder what I did wrong

```
function analyseElem(text) {
    var textMsg = msgText;
    var filtro1 = "";
    var filtro2 = "";
    var filtro3 = "";
    var filtro4 = "";

    if(textMsg[0] == '<!--') {
        var filtro1 = textMsg.replace(/<!-- react-text: /g,"");
        var filtro2 = filtro1.replace(/<!-- \/react-text -->/g,"");
        var filtro3 = filtro2.replace(/-->/g,"");
        filtro3[0] = "" //to delete the random number
        var filtro4 = filtro3.trim();
    }

    return filtro4;

}
```

Comment: You've already asked this question. The answer in jQuery is basically the same: `msgText = $(msgTextSelect).text();`

Comment: Sorry, I'm so stupid, I get it now, thank you very very very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this function 
It removes HTML comments, which is what your react tags are :)

```js
function filter(text){
 return text.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g, "")
}

$("#output").html(filter("<!-- react-text: 1052 -->Message Here<!-- /react-text -->"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r7upndeh/